# Any proved connection between Roth theorem and hartmanis stearns conjecture?

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, big-picture, computational-number-theory

Roth theorem classifies numbers into two classes, one is rational and transcendental, another is irrational algebraic numbers, by the number of solutions to the inequality (finite or infinite), and hartmanis stearns conjecture states that numbers in any base outputed in real time are  rational or  transcendental number,but are not irrational algebraic numbers. it seems that irrational algebraic numbers are hard to be approximated by rationals.

So, my question is , is there any  connection between Roth theorem and hartmanis stearns conjecture (proved or not proved)?

Comment: You misstated/ misinterpreted the Roth theorem. It says that irrational algebraic numbers can not be approximated too well, but it says nothing about transcendental numbers. It's trivial to show that there are badly approximated transcendental numbers.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin why do you think I have misunderstood it? A theorem can be applied to what is applicable.

Comment: The first paragraph of your question claims that Roth theorem tells something about the diophantine approximations to transcendental numbers (or the number of solutions of some inequalities involving transcendental numbers), which is **false**. In fact, transcendental numbers can be badly approximated, or extremely well approximated. While Roth theorem can be used to prove that **some** numbers (well approximated) are transcendental, the set of such numbers has measure 0.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin of course, since transcendental numbers have measure 1, most of them are non-computable. and even computable transcendental numbers have a lots with computational complexity that exceeds O(n3) and irrational algebraic numbers are in $O(n^3) class, I can not express every aspect of Roth theorem in my question since it is not a teaching material